# Nested Pick definition

Tags: typescript

If I had an interface with an embedded object such as:

```js
interface IStudent {
    name: string;
    address: {
        lineOne: string;
        lineTwo: string;
    }
}

const getAddressLineOne = (student: Pick<IStudent, 'address'>) => student.address.lineOne;
```

For the definition of the function, I'd really only care pick the `lineOne` part of `address`, but as far as I understand, `Pick` only allows me to go one level deep, rather than specifying further what I mean.

Is there a way to do this with typescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own `NestedPick` type:

```
type NestedPick<T, K extends string[]> = T extends object ? {
  [P in Extract<keyof T, K[0]>]: NestedPick<T[P], Tail<K>>
} : T

// get tail of tuple
type Tail<T extends any[]> = ((...args: T) => any) extends (head: any, ...tail: infer I) => any
  ? I : never
```

Haven't tested edge cases, but this might be a good starting point. Then `getAddressLineOne` looks like:

```
const getAddressLineOne = (student: NestedPick<IStudent, ['address', 'lineOne']>) =>
  student.address.lineOne;

// Test
declare const student: IStudent
const res = getAddressLineOne(student) // string
```

Alernatively, you could narrow `getAddressLineOne` function parameter:

```
const getAddressLineOne2 = (address: Pick<IStudent["address"], "lineOne">) => address.lineOne;
```

[Code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=26&ssc=49&pln=24&pc=1#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)

Comment: I'm struggling to get the `NestedPick` to be able to evaluate to the correct type; for instance, in the `getAddressLineOne`, the return type is `NestedPick<string, []>`. Any thoughts on how this could be evaluated to just `string`?

Comment: @OliverRadini updated `NestedPick` type with a check for object!